# Why is passing Int where an F[_] parameter is expected valid?

Tags: scala, higher-kinded-types

Let's say we have a function:

```
def bar[F[_], A](x: F[A], y: F[A]) = null
```

All the following behavior are clear:

```
bar(List(1, 2, 3), List(1)) // compiles ok
bar(List(1), Some(1)) // doesn't compile
```

But,

```
bar(1, List(1)) // compiles ok
bar(1, 1) // compiles ok
```

Why?

P.S. example from [FSiS Part 1 - Type Constructors, Functors, and Kind Projector](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Dsd4pc99FSY)

Comment: Both `Any` and `Nothing` are kind polymorphic—see e.g. [SI-9248](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-9248).

Comment: btw `bar(1, List(1))` doesn't compile in `2.9`, but does in `2.10`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the following gives a clue (although there is still some mystery involved):

```
def baz[F[_], A](x: F[A]): F[A] = x

scala> baz("str")
res5: Comparable[String] = str

scala> baz(1)
res6: Any = 1

scala> class Foo
defined class Foo

scala> baz(new Foo)
<console>:15: error: no type parameters for method baz: (x: F[A])F[A] exist so that it can be applied to arguments (Foo)
 --- because ---
argument expression's type is not compatible with formal parameter type;
 found   : Foo
 required: ?F
              baz(new Foo)
              ^
<console>:15: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Foo
 required: F[A]
              baz(new Foo)
                  ^

scala> case class Foo2
warning: there were 1 deprecation warning(s); re-run with -deprecation for details
defined class Foo2

scala> baz(Foo2)
res10: scala.runtime.AbstractFunction0[Foo2] = Foo2
```

So the functions `bar` and `baz` are finding any container type they can (`Comparable` for String, `AbstractFunction0` for a case class, etc) to match the expected `F[_]`.

Speculation: in the case of `Int`, I suspect we are hitting a special "container" type for what are (boxed) primitive types in the underlying bytecode. If this special type can only be printed back to Scala as "`Any`", but is really some special type we can think of as "`Any[_]`", then that could explain the results we see. As corroboration that this is to do with the special handling of primitives, note that it fails for non-primitive simple types, like the (non-case) class `Foo` above.

Answer (score 4):

I think you're running into a limitation of the type inference system.  To shed some light on this, let's look at what happens when we redefine this a bit to get a more useful output:

```
class Bar[F[_], A](x: F[A], y: F[A]) {}
res0: Bar[List,Int] = Bar@69f1a286
new Bar(List(1,2,3), List(1))
res1: Bar[Any,Int] = Bar@7b139eab
new Bar(List(1), 1)
res2: Bar[Any,Int] = Bar@456be73c
new Bar(List(1), Some(1))
<console>:12: error: inferred kinds of the type arguments (Product with java.io.Serializable,Int) do not conform to the expected kinds of the type parameters (type F,type A) in class Bar.
Product with java.io.Serializable's type parameters do not match type F's expected parameters:
<refinement of Product with java.io.Serializable> has no type parameters, but type F has one
       new Bar(List(1), Some(1))
       ^
<console>:12: error: type mismatch;
 found   : List[Int]
 required: F[A]
       new Bar(List(1), Some(1))
                   ^
<console>:12: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Some[Int]
 required: F[A]
       new Bar(List(1), Some(1))
```

In the first example, we have a `Bar[List, Int]`, which makes perfect sense, we passed in two `List[Int]`.

In the second and third, we have a `Bar[Any, Int]`.  Here's where it gets weird.  Keep in mind that `Any` is the parent of both `AnyVal` (the parent of Scala's equivalents of Java's primitives) and `AnyRef` (the Scala equivalent of Java's Object) (see [Scala Documentation](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/unified-types.html) for further explanation).

Scala's type inference has decided that this `Bar`'s constructor should accept `Any` for `F`, and `Int` for `A`.  As `Any` is indeed a parent of `List` and `Int`, that's fine.  The `List` is indeed parameterized as `[Int]`, so that's fine.  What's weird is that Scala is okay with saying that the `Int` is also of type `Any[Int]`.  I don't have a good explanation for that part.

With the last one, that's where I'm honestly confused, and I have to wonder if this is a bug.  For some reason, even though both `List` and `Some` are children of `Any`, and both are parameterized with `Int`, it doesn't allow it.  I'm afraid I'm not well versed in the intricacies of the compiler's inference methods, but for what it's worth, explicitly specify those parameters works:

```
new Bar[Any,Int](List(1), Some(1))
res14: Bar[Any,Int] = Bar@36238b12
```

To me, that suggests the type inference system just can't properly infer the types, or it's inferring types that aren't correct.

Answer (score 4):

This works because the compiler infers some types for you. Here's what this looks like with the types added into `bar`:

```
  bar[Any, Int](1, List(1)) // compile ok
  bar[Any, Nothing](1, 1) // compile ok
```

This doesn't work for `bar(List(1), Some(1))` because the compiler can't infer a type to support both `List` and `Some`. You can however downcast this like above, `bar[Any, Int](List(1), Some(1))` works.

Answer (score 4):

It seems there's something wired going on with the `Any` type in combination with the kind system.

`Any` doesn't take a type parameter:
`val i:Any[Int] = 1` gives an error, so it should be of simple kind.

`Any` can be used in a position where a higher kinded type is expected, as you showed in your example `bar[Any, Nothing](1,1)`

If we use `Any` in a higher kinded position this type parameter magically turns into a simple kind and the type parameter of this former higher kinded type is completely ignored.

When the first type parameter of `bar` is `Any` we can but any type as the second parameter and it will always compile:

```
bar[Any,String](List(1),List(2))
bar[Any, Boolean](1,2)
bar[Any, Int](List(), true)
case class A()
bar[Any, A](List, A)
```

There seems to be a problem with the type inference that leads some examples to fail without type annotations.

I have found out about this behavior by trial and error, I don't know if it's bug or a feature ;-)